# show a set is not open in infinite product topology

Tags: general-topology

Consider the topological space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ (infinite product of $\mathbb{R}$) with product topology. How do we show $(0,1)\times (0,1)\times(0,1)\times\cdots$ is not open?

Thank you!

Comment: By showing that it doesn’t contain any basic open set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Brian for the hint! This is my proof based on the hint:

With the product topology, a basis is of the form $\mathcal{B}=\{\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}I_i:I_i\text{ open in $\mathbb{R}$ }\forall i\in\mathbb{N},\text{ and there are at most finitely many $I_i\neq\mathbb{R}$}\}$. Therefore, $\forall I\in\mathcal{B}$, $I$ is not a subset of $(0,1)^\mathbb{N}$. This implies $(0,1)^\mathbb{N}$ is not open.